# Condensing ArrayList NullPointer

Tags: java, arraylist, polynomials

So I am making a program that takes in polynomial functions and does different things with it.

Right now, I am trying to make a method that checks the Polynomial that is input, which is stored as an `ArrayList`, and condensing it so everything with the same exponent gets added together.

I keep receiving a `NullPointer Exception` whenever I run the program, and I am not sure why I am receiving this. I know what the error means, but I have looked through my code and cannot see why the Polynomial is being seen as `null`.

This is my constructor

```
public ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms;

public Poly(ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms)
{
    sort(terms);
    condenseExponents();
    this.terms = terms;
}
```

And in my main class I have my `Poly` objects created like this:

```
PolyTerm poly1 = new PolyTerm(4, 3);
PolyTerm poly2 = new PolyTerm(-3, 1);
PolyTerm poly3 = new PolyTerm(15, 3);
PolyTerm poly4 = new PolyTerm(7, 2);

PolyTerm poly5 = new PolyTerm(14, 12);
PolyTerm poly6 = new PolyTerm(2, 0);
PolyTerm poly7 = new PolyTerm(19, 2);

ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms = new ArrayList<>();
    terms.add(poly1);
    terms.add(poly2);
    terms.add(poly3);
    terms.add(poly4);

ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms1 = new ArrayList<>();
    terms1.add(poly5);
    terms1.add(poly6);
    terms1.add(poly7);



Poly test = new Poly(terms);
Poly test2 = new Poly(terms1);
```

Where the first thing being taken in by the `PolyTerm` is the coefficient, and the second thing being taken in is the exponent.

So back to the Poly class.

In my constructor, I call `condenseExponents()` which is meant to condense to `ArrayList` and combine the coefficients of all similar exponents. Here is that method

```
private void condenseExponents()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < terms.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < terms.size(); j++)
        {
            if(terms.get(i).getExponent() == terms.get(j).getExponent())
                terms.set(i, new PolyTerm(terms.get(i).getCoef() + terms.get(j).getCoef(), terms.get(i).getExponent()));
                terms.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

The `NullPointer Exception` keeps being thrown on the first line of the `for loop` in that method.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `j < terms.size() - 1` instead of `j < terms.size()`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I don't think so. Since the `nested loop` is `j = i + 1`, when so when `i` gets to the last index, then `j` would try to go to an index that doesn't exist which would be a problem. I may be wrong though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign term before your function call;

```
public ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms;

public Poly(ArrayList<PolyTerm> terms)
 {
sort(terms);
this.terms = terms;
condenseExponents();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. I am confused why my `sort` method works before the assignment, but the `condense` method does not.

Comment: @brent_mb because `sort()` gets the local variable `terms` as an argument, while `condenseExponents()` tries to use the member variable.